# What verbs could you use with "ad"?

Tags: word-request

What verbs could you use with "ad"? As in

> The company ____ an ad on TV to promote their new product.

Answer (score 2):

*Put; showed; published; presented; had; displayed; promoted; introduced; sponsored; ...*

Comment: Is "put" a choice fit for both TV commercials and newspaper ads?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev It would work ok here. Though I might use "put out (a TV advert)". But were I speaking I might say "The company promoted their new product  in a TV advertisement".

Comment: You can use 'put' for many things, to save thinking up a more specific word. It's done in colloquial conversation all the time. I put a banana on the table, they put an ad on the TV, NASA put a man on the moon. It just generalises very easily.

Comment: Or [**ran** an ad](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/run-an-ad).

Comment: @Tetsujin Any ideas yourself as to a word one might use?

Answer (score 1):

On radio or TV you could use the word *aired* (this wouldn't work for a printed advert).